# Performance issues with Material-ui v5.0.6 and Meteor

Tags: meteor, material-ui, emotion

I was wondering if anyone else was having the same problems and if there are any solutions out there...

I've created an app using Material-UI and Meteor JS. All was well until I updated Material-UI to v5, where they totally changed how components were styled, now they are using @emotion.

I'm now getting a lot of noticeable performance issues with certain components on **first use**. And a lot of warnings in the console along the lines of "[Violation] 'foobar' handler took xxxxms".

For example, if you have a Material-UI Dialog that is popped up by clicking a button, then the first time that dialog is popped up, it can take 1-3 seconds. Subsequent pop-ups are 'instant'. If you force-reload the page, then again, on first use, you get the performance issue.

I wondered if it was something to do with the complexity of my app or some odd interaction, so I just created a brand new Meteor project (the default React one that has a button that increments a counter), installed Material-UI v5.0.6 and then replaced the button on the default app with a Material-UI  component.

Immediately, I get console warnings about performance issues. In this case a warning about DOMContentLoaded taking too long on page load, then one when I click the button 'mousedown' handler took 300ms.

Opening up Chrome's Performance doo-dar, I see a first click takes around 300ms and LOTS of things are going on under the hood in emotion. One subsequent clicks, very little is going on under the hood and the event is around 3ms, ie, 100x quicker.

Any thoughts on this out there?

Comment: It's a known issue. Related [discussion](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/discussions/29268) on github.

Comment: Thanks @NearHuscarl - so much for my searching!